# Error al migrar librerías de Java 8 a Java 9 o superior

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse me muestra un error en la linea de código que no se muestra, ni en el nombre de la clase en la pestaña de eclipse que le corresponde, ni en el apartado de problemas, incluso la aplicación corre sin ningún inconveniente.

He revisado las librerías y todo esta incluido. Estoy trabajando con openJDK 14

Como les digo todo funciona como si no hubiera errores. Solo que me muestra ese error en el lateral de la linea de código. Linea que se ejecuta y resuelve sin ningún problema.

Adjunto una imagen donde señalo con flechas rojas lo que les comento anteriormente.

[image: Adjunto una imagen ilustrativa, donde señalo con flechas rojas lo que describo en la pregunta]

En la siguiente imagen muestro como la aplicación corre luego de las lineas sin problemas y sin arrojar errores en consola. Y corre hasta el final sin inconvenientes.

[image: La aplicación no se detiene en los errores, sigue sin inconvenientes]

Mi consulta en definitiva, es que puede estar pasando y que puedo intentar para resolverlo. Puede ser un problema de openJDK, estoy empezando a usarlo. Y esto no me había pasado antes utilizando jdk.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

EDITO:

GridBagConstraints.BOTH y  GridBagConstraints.WEST son costantes de tipo int declaradas en la clase GridBagConstraints de la siguiente manera:

```
public static final int BOTH = 1; 
public static final int WEST = 17;
```

EDITO2:

Apoyándome en el comentario de Alex, cambie la librería del proyecto a JAVA 8 y el error desaparece, el mismo vuelva a aparecer con JAVA 9 en adelante.

Yo quiero pode utilizar la ultima versión de OpenJDK, por eso estoy interesado en resolverlo más que en cambiar la versión de la librería. Pero no se bien por donde estudiar el tema.

Comment: Es porque en tu método `UbicarComponentes` estas declarando valores en `int` y pero en la parte de tu error declaras `GridBagConstraints`. La verdad es que he de suponer que eso es un `objeto` ¿Probaste convirtiendo eso en un `int`? Desconozco como se convierten valores en eclipse pero sería esta lógica: `Convert.Int32(GridBagContraints.Both)`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta!

BOTH  y WEST son constantes de tipo int declaradas en el objeto GridBagContraints. 

De todos modos probé hacer lo que dices, de las dos formas que se me ocurrio:

1ero- reemplazando las constantes por variables int con sus respectivos valores.

2do- también probé colocando directamente los valores 1 y 17 que son los que corresponden a las constantes.

Comment: Asi se declaran Dichas constantes en el objeto GridBagContraints

   public static final int BOTH = 1;
 public static final int WEST = 17;

Comment: El problema podría ser como Eclipse utiliza los módulos del SDK. Desde Java 9, el módulo que incluye awt/swing (que es donde está la clase `GridBagConstraint`) no se incluye por defecto en el SDK, 
Podría ser que cuando ejecutas la aplicación la configuración de módulos sea distinta a la que usa Eclipse en su compilador. Yo buscaría por ese lado.
Por otra parte, dices que intentaste reemplazar las constantes por ints diréctamente, pero no dices que ocurrió en ese caso. Removiste tambien el import de GridBagConstraint?

Comment: Alex muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Cambiando las variables por int, sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo. La aplicación corre sin problemas y el mensaje de error sigue apareciendo en la linea.

Probé cambiar la librería del proyecto a JAVA 8 y ahí si desaparece el error. Que vuelve con cualquier versión de java 9 en adelante.

Por lo que deduzco que el problema viene por el lado que comentas tú. Voy a seguir estudiando el tema. Si tienes algún punto que pueda ayudarme a buscar la información correcta estaría muy agradecido, me siento un poco perdido. Pero sigo investigando. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me llevó un poquito de estudio entender lo que decía Alex, dejo la solución por si le sirve a alguien.

La instancia UbicarEnLayout refiere a una clase ubicada en una librería no modular hecha en java 8

La clase donde se daba el problema es un proyecto nuevo con openJdk14 y modular.

La solución que encontré fue crear un nuevo proyecto modular para la librería donde se encuentra UbicarEnLayout donde module-info.java contiene

```
module referenciasMisLibrerias {
requires java.desktop; // modulo que contiene   GridBagConstraint  
exports utilidades;
```

}

el paquete utilidades contiene la clase UbicarEnLayout

en el moduel-info.java del proyecto donde se daba el problema puse:

```
module ReferenciasPrepararImportacion {
    requires java.desktop;
    requires referenciasMisLibrerias;
}
```

java.desktop es el modulo que contiene la clase GridBagConstraint

Espero haber sido claro, quedo a las órdenes para cualquier eventual aclaración